# Cell double click functionality

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I need to implement double click functionality on Jquery full calendar plugin. It supports day click feature for basic views. but I need to submit a form when user double click in cell(eg. 4.00 - 4.30 slot) with start time and end time in both agendaWeek view and agendaDay view too.

If anyone can help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuert [dblclick](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/).

On your div target:

```
$( "#target" ).dblclick(function() {
   /* do your stuff */
});
```

I don't know how fullcalendar works, but I suppose that create many elements of a certain class (like "cellElement") so:

```
 $('.cellElement').dblclick(function() {
   console.log("Cell: ", $(this));
 });
```

## update

I checked out fullcalendar, you can do:

```
 $('.ui-widget-content').dblclick(function() {
     /* whatever */
 });
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/G6K6Y/1043/)

Comment: I'd recommend prefixing beyond the .ui-widget-content class which will attach events to other jquery ui dom elements all over the place.